# Rewrite everything that is not a file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to have everything that looks like this:

```
/1/2/3/4/5/[...]
```

to redirect to this:

```
/index.php?u=/1/2/3/4/5/[...]
```

**unless** the requested string is a specific file. So anything that doesn't have a `.` (dot), I want to redirect to `index.php?u=[...]`. I'll then parse the URI segments in PHP to determine what the user is requesting.

I've been looking around for how to do this, but have only a very rough understanding of regular expressions and have been unable to find an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, figured it out. I found it's easier to match if something **is** in a string rather than if it **isn't** in a string, so this is what I came up with:

```
^.*\..*$ -> /$0

[stop matching if found]

^.*$ -> /index.php?u=$0
```

Not correct syntax of course, but you can easily adapt it to any number of rerouting systems.

Answer (score 1):

In Apache mod_rewrite you can check if the request is for a physical file with a condition such as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

This is better than checking for a `.` (dot) in the filename - which could simply be present in the URL. To negate an expression simply prefix it with `!`. So, `!-f` matches if the file does not exist.

To internally rewrite *everything else* to `index.php?u=XXX`, where `XXX` is the original request then add:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^u=
RewriteRule .* index.php?u=/$0 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive is necessary to prevent a rewrite loop and basically checks that `?u=` is not already present in the requested URL. Note that this is an "internal rewrite" - the URL in the address bar does not change. To externally redirect add the `R` flag on the `RewriteRule`, ie `[R,L]`.

Bringing this all together in a .htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^u=
RewriteRule .* index.php?u=/$0 [L]
```

If you only want to do this for specific URLs then modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (the first argument). So, for URLs that look like `/1/2/3/4/5/[...]`:

```
RewriteRule ^1/2/3/4/5.* index.php?u=/$0 [L]
```

The slash prefix on the *pattern* should be omitted for per-directory .htaccess files.